# db_select order by custom field value

Tags: nodes, database

I need to get all nodes of some content type and order them by integer field of this content type.

```
$nodes = db_select('node', 'n')
    ->fields('n', array('nid'))
    ->join('content_type_field_name', 'p', 'p.entity_id = n.nid')
    ->condition('n.type', 'content_type_name')
    ->orderBy('p.content_type_field_name', 'DESC')
    ->execute()
    ->fetchAll();
```

But it does not work.

What should I do?

Comment: You just need to fix the query so it matches the SQL you want to run. Beyond that it's difficult to give advice, as there aren't any details in the question; _does not work_ doesn't give anything to work with

Comment: does not work  means that my site return me:  "unable to handle this request."

Comment: Ok, you need to find out _why_ that's happening. It's not possible to debug your site from here, obviously, so either you need to do that yourself, or provide enough details in your question (not in the comments) that a person who has no idea how your site is built or laid out, might have a chance of understanding what you're asking. Start by explaining what the table you're joining in is, for example, as it doesn't have the name of any table that would be created by Drupal. If it's a module doing it, which module? Why are you using this and not the established `EntityFieldQuery`? And so on

Comment: @Clive I don't know how to do this select. I found this solution here https://www.reddit.com/r/drupal/comments/3yb7u4/order_by_custom_field/ But I don't found any tutorial in which will be written how to use this db_select in order to fetch ordering data. So I write here with mind that someone will help me and write an example how to order nodes by custom field

Comment: That's the problem - your code is correct, assuming that you're trying to order by a field called `content_type_field_name` in a table called `content_type_field_name`, that's joined by `entity_id` to the node's `nid` field. So without knowing what you _want_ the query to be, it's basically impossible to help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are using wrong Table name and wrong Field name also. Your query should look like something below:

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');

$query->join('YOUR_TABLE_NAME', 'p', 'p.entity_id = n.nid');

$query
  ->fields('n', array('nid'))
  ->condition('n.type', 'content_type_name')
  ->condition('n.status', '1')
  ->orderBy('p.YOUR_CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME', 'DESC');

$results = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
```

Comment: what's YOUR_TABLE_NAME? If you just create a content-type you won't have your own table. Can you give more details what it means? Which table?

Comment: 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME' is referring to the field's own table. Whenever you add a new field in the content type, Drupal creates a table for that new field for example field name is 'field_custom' then table's name for this field will be 'field_data_field_custom'

Comment: and what's exactly YOUR_CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME?